# Help with wording of a sentence

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

I want to construct a sentence that says the following:

**Objects belonging to a king should be treated in a certain way, and what you presented is clearly an object of this kind.**

I couldn't find a nice way to phrase it:

> -Why did you paint the ball yellow?
>
> -Because you didn't ask me to paint the ball blue.
>
> -Well, all balls should be painted blue, I told so in the meeting yesterday.
>
> -*Then please write this on the bulletin board. Policies, which what this clearly is, should be posted on the bulletin board.*

How should I phrase the last sentence?

Comment: There is a missing "is" after "which". Other than that, the sentence is grammatical.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, wouldn't there be too many "is"s there?

Comment: No. The "is's" are wholly necessary; if the "is" RedDwight refers to is not added, consider the sentence ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then please write this on the bulletin board: policies, which **is** what this clearly is, should be posted on the bulletin board.

I spotted an error in sentence #3--the last clause (I told (you) so in the meeting last week) cannot be appended to the remainder by the arbitrary addition of a comma followed by no corresponding conjunction; it must be replaced with a dash; otherwise, it will face ungrammaticality. Moreover, the final clause is rather unrelated; so do not add a conjunction to extend the sentence (to avoid having two unrelated clauses connected).

Good luck.

Comment: So how would you rephrase the 3rd sentence to not have two unrelated clauses connected?

Comment: Add a dash in substitution of the third comma. The rest is fine.

Comment: Also, you must add a "you" in "I told (you) so".

Comment: But if the you isn't appropriate, for example, if it was said yesterday, but I wasn't present. The meaning id that it was announced at the meeting, with the underlining assumption that if something is said in the meeting, then everyone should be aware of it, even if they weren't present at the time.